# All validation errors displaying in CMS (pulling data from api call into CMS)

Tags: php, api, validation, content-management-system

I'm trying to pull data from an API and when the information is pulled into the fieldsets within my CMS, I want to ensure that whatever has been pulled from the API is validated properly with the rules I currently have set up within my CMS (eg. an image can be no bigger that 1920x1080 in dimensions).

Here is my code:

```
use App\Utilities\BardUtil;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\Exception\GuzzleException;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;
use Statamic\Eloquent\Entries\EntryModel;
use Statamic\Events\EntrySaved;
use Statamic\Facades\Entry;

public function handle(EntrySaved $event): void
{
    $entry = $event->entry->model();
    if ($entry->collection != 'companies') {
        return;
    }
    $data = collect($entry->data);
    if (!isset($data['tickers'][0])) {
        return;
    }
    $tickerId = $data['tickers'][0];

    $ticker = EntryModel::find($tickerId);
    if ($ticker && $ticker->title) {
        $tickerTitle = $ticker->title;

        $response = Http::get('apicallurlexample');

        $fields = $event->entry->blueprint()->fields();
        $items = $response->json('results.0');
        $items['companyName'] = $items['exchangeName'];
        $data = $data->merge($items);
        $data['slug'] = $entry->slug;
        $data['date'] = $entry->date;

        $fields = $fields->addValues($data->toArray());

        $collection = $event->entry->collection();
        $site = $event->entry->site();
        $rules = Entry::updateRules($collection, $site);
        $replacements = [
            'id' => $entry->id,
            'collection' => $collection,
            'site' => $site,
        ];

        $fields
            ->validator()
            ->withRules($rules)
            ->withReplacements($replacements)
            ->validate();

        $event->entry->data($fields->values()->all());
        $event->entry->saveQuietly();
    }
}
```

I think the issue lies within the following code:

```
$fields
            ->validator()
            ->withRules($rules)
            ->withReplacements($replacements)
            ->validate();
```

What's happening when I save the company details is that it displays all the validation errors, even if the data hasn't went against any of the rules. Any help would be appreciated and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the rather late reply but thought I'd update this thread anyways for others who find this later.

Statamic only uses the validation rules you define in your blueprint/fieldset when saving entries/terms/etc in the Control Panel.

When you save data manually (eg. via PHP or directly editing the Markdown files), no validation checks are ran on it. You'll need to manually do any kind of validation in your code, before the entry is created in Statamic.